# How to edit an object created using a bezier curve and previously converted to a mesh

Tags: edit-mode

I created a hose using a bezier curve and now I want to change its length and curves. When I select the object in edit all the geometry is displayed and so I guess I must have converted the bezier curve to a mesh.
But how do I get it back to the 'state' to was where I could select a 'thingy'/tool which looked like a short edge which I could drag and change the direction (sorry I don't know the terminology but it looks like the image below of a much different house in another model.
I have tried selecting Object > convert > curve which didn't solve this problem.
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you convert a curve to mesh, then convert back to curve, you won't get the original curve if this is your question, so it's better to set the correct length before converting to mesh (or simply don't convert to mesh if you don't need to, it all depends on the final goal)

Comment: Thanks moonboots. I was thinking along those lines bust wasn't sure.  I think it would be easier for me to recreate my simple' hose object. The only reason I was trying to lengthen the hose (after converting to mesh) was to emulate better the hose I am trying to copy (in real life on a dock) which is longer than I first noticed. Actually I don't even remember converting the curve to mesh in the first place as I had noted that when exporting to a  gLtf it automatically converted during that process (and the original curve remained). Thanks again.

Comment: If you still want to convert back to a curve it's possible to do it even though it won't be exactly as the original one, it takes several steps, tell me if you want me to detail, but it may be quicker to redo it from scratch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert a curve to mesh, then convert back to curve, you won't get the original curve if this is your question, so it's better to set the correct length before converting to mesh (or simply don't convert to mesh if you don't need to, it all depends on the final goal).

From the current object, what you could do:

First select all and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to convert tris to quads:

[image]

Then select an edge loop and separate the selection as a new object (<kbd>P</kbd>):

[image]

Select all and press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* in order to simplify, tweak the *Angle* value in the *Operator Box*:

[image]

Then <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>M</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> and convert to a curve:

[image]

Convert the curve from *Poly* to a *Bezier*:

[image]

Then select all the points and press <kbd>V</kbd> > *Automatic* to have a round curve:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I call that 'magic'. You would probably call it 'elementary'.  Thanks again for educating me further.